# How to test scope values after service call http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test to test that tests a factory that performs a http.get and then tests the scope bindings.

The factory is called within my controller.

Here's a plunker showing my http.get: http://plnkr.co/edit/VqUSeTiEj3MP37tAXKad?p=preview

Ctrl:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, factoryGetJSONFile) {  

$scope.name = 'World';

  factoryGetJSONFile.getMyData(function(data) {
    $scope.Addresses = data.Addresses.AddressList;
    $scope.People = data.Names.People;
    $scope.Country = data.Country;
  });

});
```

Test:

```
describe('with httpBackend', function () {
    var app;
    beforeEach(function () {
        app = angular.mock.module('plunker')
    });

    describe('MyCtrl', function () {
        var scope, ctrl, theService, httpMock;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, factoryGetJSONFile, $httpBackend) {
            httpMock = $httpBackend;
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {
                $scope: scope,
                factoryGetJSONFile: factoryGetJSONFile,
                $httpBackend: httpMock
            });
        }));

        it("should make a GET call to data.json", function () {
            console.log("********** SERVICE ***********");
            httpMock.expectGET("data.json?").respond(data);

            console.log(data.Addresses);
            console.log(data.Names);
            console.log(data.Country);
            //expect(factoryGetJSONFile.getMyData()).toBeDefined();
            httpMock.flush();
        });
    })
});
```

The test for the http.get seems ok, but when i try logging the reponse (data), an error occurs.

UPDATE:

When i try to log the call via:

```
console.log(httpMock.expectGET("data.json?").respond(data));
```

Undefined is displayed.

Comment: @DoctorMick - I get this message: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data.... I expected data to be the result of the service call that gets the JSON

Comment: From my understanding, you're telling the httpMock to return a result of data whenever a request is made but data isn't defined in your test anywhere (that I can see).  Try adding var data = { bananas: "are yellow" } before httpMock.expectGet.

Comment: @DoctorMick - Tried the above, adding before the httpMock and console.log was Object{bananas: 'are yellow'}... So, how can i get data to be the JSON contents?

Comment: Do you really need it to be?  In your test I guess all you want to do is make sure the values are correctly set on the scope?  If so, you don't need the actual json, just use an empty structure that you can compare the scope values against.

Comment: @DoctorMick - ah ok, that makes sense. Could maybe use something like https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-json-fixtures-preprocessor too.